# Login with different role (redirect to different page according to user type )

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am new to php. I could not log in either from the user or the admin. How do make it so the user could log in and will be redirected to index.php, and once the admin login will be redirected to admin.php.

I did some research with youtube and could not find anything helpful on what I need.

```
  <form action="login.php" method="post">

  <input class="space" name="username" type="text" 
  placeholder="Username/E- 
  mail" required="required"></input>

  <br />

  <input class="space" name="password" type="password" 
  placeholder="Password" required="required"></input>

  <br />

  <input type="submit" class="log-btn" value="Login" />

  <button type="button" class="log-btn" onclick="return 
  abc(1,'reg.html')">Register</button>

  </form>
```

This is the database table:

[image]

I had also included the admin username and password in the database so admin does not have to register

```
<?php
include ("conn.php");
session_start();

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' and 
    password = '".$_REQUEST['password']."' or username = 
    '".$_REQUEST['username']."' and password = '".$_REQUEST['password']."' 
    LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0) {
    $cred = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $cred[1];
    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php?msg=Invalid+Credential'; 
        </script>";
}
if ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $_SESSION['role']=$row['user_role'];
}
if ($row['user_role']==="1"]) {
    echo "<script>alert('Welcome back admin!');";
    echo "window.location.href='admin.html';</script>";
}
```

I expect that the user will be able to login and will be redirected to the index.php and the admin will be able to login as well as but will be redirected to the admin.php. But what I am seeing a white page and some error code on line 20. I know my if-else statement has some issue but not sure on how to fix it to be working

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You do not need an OR in your query.

Comment: Your code is full of vulnerabilities. Have you considered using some sort of framework (e.g. Laravel) to handle user registration and logging in securely?

Comment: Not sure why you're using JavaScript redirects when you could use PHP's more easily.

Comment: Erm.. not really sure on how to improve my vulnerabilities as I am only starting on php as for now how do I make it work?(how can I improve my if else statement to make it work) but will surely look into how to improve my vulnerabilities as well as avoiding sql injection attacks in the near future.

Comment: Use PHP function header (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: This condition `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0)` interprets to "if there are no results" and failed you silently.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner What if there are -3 results? Ah? Ah? You never thought of that, did you!?

Comment: Got me there @Mike *heh!*

Answer (score 0):

Your login.php should be like this:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "dbpass", "dbname"); // make seperate file

if($_POST){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        session_start();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($row['role'] == 1){
                $_SESSION['message'] = $row['username'];
                header("Location: admin.php");exit();
            }else{
                $_SESSION['message'] = $row['username'];
                header("Location: index.php");exit();
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "Wrong Credentials";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>



<form action="login.php" method="post">

  <input class="space" name="username" type="text" 
  placeholder="Username/E- 
  mail" required="required"></input>

  <br />

  <input class="space" name="password" type="password" 
  placeholder="Password" required="required"></input>

  <br />

  <input type="submit" class="log-btn" value="Login" />

  <button type="button" class="log-btn" onclick="return 
  abc(1,'reg.html')">Register</button>

  </form>
```

And For Both page admin.php and index.php you check active session using `$_SESSION['message']`.

In that you will get the name of the user.

**NOTE:** Please do not use store plain text passwords! Please use PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for password security.

Comment: @dharman Yes, I understand the SQL Injections, But that code is not whole correct and I just try to solve that coding problem in minimum words, Nothing else

Comment: Ok, Updating Thanks

Comment: This will fix I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198743/discussion-between-ranjan-and-dharman).

Comment: but from what I see is that you only have 2 entities from the SELECT sql statement then how do you determine which user role is logged in? still not quite get the code.

Comment: On $row in while statement you will get the all columns that we mention is sql query "Select * From", $row['role'] == 1 means user is "admin" and else other role.